# How to delete a chrome browser user profile?

Tags: google-chrome

Ive got several users setup in chrome using the profile option.

Some of these are defunct and i would like to delete them.

Any idea how i can do this ? Ive had a look but cant see anything obvious.

Im running the latest version of the (as of time of writing) on MacOS BigSur.

Comment: Does [How to Find Your Chrome Profile Folder on Windows, Mac, and Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/255653/how-to-find-your-chrome-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/) answer you question?

Answer (score 0):

Removing a profile from Chrome means the deletion of the profile's bookmarks,
history, passwords, and all other settings.

To remove a Chrome profile:

- Open Chrome
- At the top right, click the profile image [image]
- Select the Settings button next to "Other profiles"
- At the top right of the profile you want to remove,
  click the three-dots menu
- Select "Delete"
- To confirm, click Delete.